# On premise SpamTitan appliance injecting IP routes

Tags: routing, ip

We recently migrated to a new firewall and most things were okay apart from email flow. There was a queue on SpamTitan which wouldn't release. When I checked the routing table, rather than using the default gateway it had been routing directly to the old firewall (rather than to the core L3 switch). The only way to fix it was to reboot the appliance. However, it's still bypassing the default gateway and going directly to the new firewall. The SpamTitan support guys couldn't see anything wrong with the appliance and suggested there was some dynamic routing going in. There isn't, it's just statically set everywhere.

The setup is:

SpamTitan (192.168.1.6)-->Core L3 Switch (192.168.1.50)-->Firewall (192.168.1.70)

[Routing table image as I can't format it in the text below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JJFG.png)

The current routing table is this:

Internet:
Destination    Gateway        Flags    Netif
default        192.168.1.50   UGS      em0
1.68.169.119   192.168.1.70   UGHD     em0
1.119.129.17   192.168.1.70   UGHD     em0
1.186.104.237  192.168.1.70   UGHD     em0

I tried to find out what the flags mean, but I couldn't find any explanation of what they mean in practice, just a copy and pasted definition of what they mean.

Day-to-day it causes no issue, but if I need to make changes at the core level, then the SpamTitan box is just going to ignore this (and possibly some other appliances)?

Comment: do the ips belongs to you or do know the owner?

Comment: The IPs are all under our control.